# App working fine on localhost but doesn't loads on netlify?

Tags: reactjs, github, https, deployment, netlify

i am trying to deploy it now, the app works great on localhost, no problems at all but when i deploy it to netlify from github it crashes by giving me these errors in developers console.

```
init @ include.preload.js:442
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://5cfc2538a4fc311e18e72538--brave-poincare-d969b9.netlify.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://video-react.js.org/assets/video-react.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
2.0370c799.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.dbd098f2.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
include.preload.js:442 [Deprecation] Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use Element.attachShadow instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960 for more details.
init @ include.preload.js:442
include.preload.js:442 [Deprecation] Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use Element.attachShadow instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960 for more details.
init @ include.preload.js:442
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://5cfc2538a4fc311e18e72538--brave-poincare-d969b9.netlify.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://video-react.js.org/assets/video-react.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

it was not being able to install node-pre-gyp module before, but i fixed it but now it gets deployed but doesn't work

complete log of netlify deployement:

```
5:14:32 PM: Build ready to start
5:14:34 PM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
5:14:34 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
5:14:34 PM: buildbot version: 75cd99f62ada9e21edea53208e8baf0eab85a045
5:14:35 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
5:14:35 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
5:14:35 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
5:14:35 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
5:14:35 PM: git clone https://github.com/Phyxable/app-jun-07
5:14:50 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
5:14:51 PM: Starting build script
5:14:51 PM: Installing dependencies
5:14:53 PM: Downloading and installing node v10.16.0...
5:14:53 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
5:14:53 PM: 
#######
5:14:53 PM:          11.0%
5:14:53 PM: 
###############################################################
5:14:53 PM: ###        91.8%
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: #
5:14:54 PM: ################
5:14:54 PM: ########################################## 100.0%
5:14:54 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
5:14:54 PM: Checksums matched!
5:14:56 PM: Now using node v10.16.0 (npm v6.9.0)
5:14:57 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
5:14:58 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
5:14:58 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
5:14:58 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
5:15:00 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
5:15:00 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.9.0
5:15:33 PM: > grpc@1.20.3 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/grpc
5:15:33 PM: > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
5:15:33 PM: node-pre-gyp
5:15:33 PM: WARN
5:15:33 PM:  Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
5:15:34 PM: [grpc] Success: "/opt/build/repo/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
5:15:34 PM: > core-js-pure@3.1.3 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js-pure
5:15:34 PM: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
5:15:34 PM: Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!
5:15:34 PM: The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
5:15:34 PM: > https://opencollective.com/core-js 
5:15:34 PM: > https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 
5:15:34 PM: Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)
5:15:34 PM: > protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/protobufjs
5:15:34 PM: > node scripts/postinstall
5:15:35 PM: > jss@9.8.7 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/jss
5:15:35 PM: > node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove JSS? You can now support us on open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/jss/donate\u001b[0m')"
5:15:35 PM: Love JSS? You can now support us on open collective:
5:15:35 PM:  > https://opencollective.com/jss/donate
5:15:35 PM: > firebase-functions@2.3.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/firebase-functions
5:15:35 PM: > node ./upgrade-warning
5:15:35 PM: ======== WARNING! ========
5:15:35 PM: This upgrade of firebase-functions contains breaking changes if you are upgrading from a version below v1.0.0.
5:15:35 PM: To see a complete list of these breaking changes, please go to:
5:15:35 PM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff
5:15:37 PM: npm WARN
5:15:37 PM: optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
5:15:37 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
5:15:37 PM: npm WARN
5:15:37 PM:  optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
5:15:37 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
5:15:37 PM: npm
5:15:37 PM: WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.6 (node_modules/fsevents):
5:15:37 PM: npm
5:15:37 PM:  WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
5:15:37 PM: added 1849 packages from 1018 contributors and audited 890418 packages in 35.912s
5:15:37 PM: found 0 vulnerabilities
5:15:37 PM: NPM modules installed
5:15:37 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
5:15:37 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
5:15:38 PM: unset GOOS;
5:15:38 PM: unset GOARCH;
5:15:38 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
5:15:38 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
5:15:38 PM: go version >&2;
5:15:38 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
5:15:38 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
5:15:38 PM: Installing missing commands
5:15:38 PM: Verify run directory
5:15:38 PM: Executing user command: npm run build
5:15:38 PM: > finalphyx@0.1.0 build /opt/build/repo
5:15:38 PM: > react-scripts build && echo '/*    /index.html   200' > build/_redirects
5:15:39 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
5:16:15 PM: Compiled with warnings.
5:16:15 PM: ./src/Components/App/index.js
5:16:15 PM:   Line 13:   'FourZeroFourPage' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
5:16:15 PM:   Line 15:  'Switch' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
5:16:15 PM: ./src/Pages/SubscribePage/index.jsx
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "Phyxable",
  "name": "Phyxable",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icon-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "background_color": "#3367D6",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "theme_color": "#3367D6"
}
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "finalphyx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/lab": "^3.0.0-alpha.30",
    "disable-scroll": "^0.4.1",
    "firebase": "^6.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "mdbreact": "^4.15.0",
    "netlify": "^2.4.6",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-div-100vh": "^0.3.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-firebaseui": "^3.1.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
    "react-jw-player": "^1.19.0",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.7.4",
    "react-password-mask": "^3.3.1",
    "react-player": "^1.11.0",
    "react-responsive": "^7.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.11",
    "react-share": "^3.0.0",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^3.0.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "stripe": "^7.1.0",
    "video-react": "^0.13.7",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1",
    "window-scroll-manager": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && echo '/*    /index.html   200' > build/_redirects",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "aws s3 sync build s3://www.phyxable.com"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://jacobmjones@bitbucket.org/jacobmjones/web.git"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/jacobmjones/web#readme",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

it should be working fine as it works great on localhost but doesn't.

Comment: I think netlify only deploys static websites.

Comment: @MonicaAcha No we have a previous build as well on netlify of the same product this one contains some small changes. that was a different developer . so if it worked then it should work now as well.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT*** I was able to resolve this by changing the `packages.json` file..

***From this:***

```
  ...
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/jacobmjones/web#readme",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
  ...
```

***To this:***

```
  ...
  "homepage": "/",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
  ...
```

This is happening due to [mixed content](https://outspokenmedia.com/https/mixed-content/) which is preventing your `CSS` from loading...

Wherever you are importing this `CSS` within your app: `'http://video-react.js.org/assets/video-react.css'`..

..*change it to this, and it should work:*

**`'https://video-react.js.org/assets/video-react.css'`**

Notice the `https`... You cannot use `XHR` on a secure (`https`) connection to retrieve resources on an insecure connection (`http`).. Your Netlify site is on `https` and that `CSS` file is on `http` - which qualifies for `mixed-content`.

- [Chrome
  docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)
- [Mozilla/Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

Comment: Thank you very much i got rid of the mixed content errors by putting the stylesheets in local folder instead of on a server. But still getting those unexpected token errors.

Comment: And if you run "npm build" (or "npm run build" - I can't remember which you have to run) locally, it works just fine?

Comment: on local machine i have to run `npm start and yea it works fine locally.

Comment: Npm start doesn't build files like netlify does. Can you run npm build to see if you get errors?

Comment: What i noticed is that the file names that  i get errors on, in the developers console don't even exist.

Comment: Correct - that is what the other answer mentioned (by @JoelH) - when Webpack builds the files for you, it appends a unique GUID - therefore, when Netlify builds your code the file names change... is the code for this on a public repo? I could try to get it on Netlify to see if I get the same error..?

Comment: When you go to build it in Netlify, what does your Build Command look like? https://i.imgur.com/IXTrqn7.png

Comment: `npm run build`

Comment: What does your publish directory look like? Are you using `create-react-app`?  I was able to publish a vanilla react app here, without issue: https://elated-lewin-969493.netlify.com/

Comment: Can i get your email i'll send you the link to repository.yes it is a create react app

Comment: https://5cfe8d96e8bb045d6d16016a--serene-curran-0d9366.netlify.com/. You can see the errors in developers console. i got the email

Answer (score 1):

Error seems to be in 'unexpected token <'

The error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < is most commonly caused by your site’s code referring to an asset that is no longer available. Most commonly, this is due to a filename change in assets generated during your build. The same situation happens if you use versioned or chunked javascript where the filename changes with every deploy.

Source: https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-why-do-i-see-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-errors-how-can-i-use-chunking-or-versioning-for-my-assets-at-netlify/124

In addition, See if you can get any clues from here:
https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-gotchas/

Also, try upgrading node version to the latest one.

Comment: Hi thank you for the tip. i am actually stuck on that because the errors that i am getting is on those files. Because after the code builds the file name if the JS chunks gets changed to something else. I have never worked on this stuff before can you please suggest me how can i fix that?